# How can I update flexmonster toolbar in real time?

Tags: javascript, web, charts, flexmonster

I'm using flexmonster chart in my project, in the toolbar, I have a button with a custom menu. once the user is saving the data I want to add / delete items from that menu. in flexmonster documentation they say that I can change the toolbar by overriding the `getTabs` method:

```
let tabs = toolbar.getTabs(); 
  toolbar.getTabs = function () {
    // remove the Connect tab using its id
    tabs = tabs.filter(tab => tab.id != "fm-tab-connect");
    return tabs; 
  }
```

however, that only works before the chart is rendered.  is there a way to update the chart in real time after the chart is already rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `updateToolbar` method provided by `Flexmonster`.

```
const pivot = new Flexmonster({
  container: "pivot-container",
  toolbar: true,
});

function updateToolbar() {
  const tabs = pivot.toolbar.getTabs();
  // Modify the tabs array as needed, e.g., add or delete items

  // Remove the Connect tab using its id for instance
  const updatedTabs = tabs.filter((tab) => tab.id !== "fm-tab-connect");

  // Update the toolbar with the modified tabs
  pivot.toolbar.updateTabs(updatedTabs);
}

// Call the updateToolbar function whenever needed, e.g., after data is saved
updateToolbar();
```

[Documentation 1](https://www.flexmonster.com/api/) [Documentation 2](https://www.flexmonster.com/doc/customizing-toolbar/) [Documentation 3](https://www.flexmonster.com/demos/js/pivot-table/)

Comment: i couldn't find a method for updating the toolbar (including updateToolbar) in their  library

Comment: Check this [link](https://www.flexmonster.com/doc/customizing-toolbar/)

Comment: yes. that's where i got my snipper from